# When was Doctor Who first broadcast in the USA?

Tags: doctor-who

A post by Satan2016 at:

https://moviechat.org/tt0056751/Doctor-Who/62a102b6e8e40e2cb2ce3d22/1975

Gives the dates when *Doctor Who* (1963-1989) was first seen in various countries.

> USA 29 September 1975
> Canada and Australia 1965!

I remember at least some episodes of Doctor Who were seen in at least some parts of the USA before 1975.

I remember beginning to watch Doctor Who in the mid 1970s.   I think that the first episode I watched was from the 1975 season, probably an episode of "Revenge of the Cybermen", at the same time or after it was broadcast in the UK.   And I remember watching those episodes on my grandmother's color television.

As I remember,  I watched the first season of *Space 1999* (1975-1977) on black and white TV and the second season on color TV, so the date my grandmother got a color TV should should depend on when the seasons of *Space 1999* were shown in the USA.

I also remember that Doctor Who was on TV in the USA years before that.  I specifically remember watching the ending of "Doctor Who and the Silurians" in the USA at the same time or after it was first broadcast on 14 March 1970.

[added 02-17-2024.  According to the information in alexg's answer and the link there, since I always lived in the Philadelphia region, it seems certain that I watched the last episode of "Dr. Who and the Silurians" on station WPHL channel 17. And it would have been on Tuesday, 29 August or weds. 8 November 1972.]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The BroaDWcast wiki [records](https://broadwcast.org/index.php/United_States--1972) the first broadcast episode of *Doctor Who* in the USA as 7:30 PM, Monday 21 August 1972, in Philadelphia (WPHL). The synopsis in the Philadelphia Inquirer TV listings,

> Investigating strong irregularities at the site of an atomic research station, Dr. Who is attacked by a prehistoric monster

is certainly for "Doctor Who and the Silurians", although there are many prehistoric monsters and atomic research stations in the Pertwee era. A more complete [listing of airdates](https://broadwcast.org/index.php/Airdates_in_Philadelphia_(WPHL)) is available,  and there are [similar records](https://broadwcast.org/index.php/Category:Airdates) for other places in the USA. If you remember where you lived at the time - and perhaps even which channel you were watching - you may be able to find a more precise timing for the Silurians finale. For example, this was in Boston (WGBH) on 17 Feb 1976; Los Angeles (KCET) on 12 August 1975; Orlando (WFTV) on 20 October 1972; etc.

If the information is missing from the wiki then it's possible that an old digitized TV guide might have it.

In any case, you are correct that *Doctor Who* TV episodes came to the USA before 1975. Apparently, the BBC tried to sell it there from fairly early on, but without success. The two Peter Cushing movies were shown but not the TV programme itself.

Comment: Since I always lived in the Philadelphia region, it seems certain that I watched the last episode of "Dr. Who and the Silurieans" on station WPHL channel 17.  And it would have been on Tuesday, 29 August or weds. 8 November 1972 according to the schedule in your link.